# GKE - "Migrate to updated APIs" but cannot find any resources for it

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

My GKE cluster shows notifications `Migrate to updated APIs` since yesterday, but I cannot find any resources with the given api. How can I find what makes these errors?

**1. PodSecurityPolicy**

The message tells that I called `podsecuritypolicy` api, but I could only find `gce.gke-metrics-agent` which all the gke clusters have.

[image]

```
> kubectl get --raw /apis/policy/v1beta1/podsecuritypolicies | jq
Warning: policy/v1beta1 PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+
{
  "kind": "PodSecurityPolicyList",
  "apiVersion": "policy/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "157895762"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "gce.gke-metrics-agent",
        "uid": "8d3f2f60-a1d4-4b20-9980-cdcd40fad7a1",
        "resourceVersion": "81300748",
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-02-01T07:21:26Z",
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**2. HorizontalPodAutoScaler**

There is no resource for `autoscaling/v2beta2/horizontalpodautoscaler` in my cluster too.

[image]

```
> kubectl get --raw /apis/autoscaling/v2beta2/horizontalpodautoscalers --all-namespaces | jq
Warning: autoscaling/v2beta2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler is deprecated in v1.23+, unavailable in v1.26+; use autoscaling/v2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler
{
  "kind": "HorizontalPodAutoscalerList",
  "apiVersion": "autoscaling/v2beta2",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "162819907"
  },
  "items": []
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also seeing the same error but we are not using any HPA resources. I wonder if its related to the cluster autoscaling settings?

Comment: @boneys I finally solved this by adding `resource.exclusions` to `argocd-cm`. You can find the details [here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/12382#issuecomment-1689520069).

Comment: You command helped me find resources that required to be migrated on EKS. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PodSecurityPolicies it sounds like ArgoCD controller is making calls to the API Server to check if you have any. Even if you did not create them explicitly it's possible a controller inside your cluster is checking as if these objects exist. The GKE upgrade assistance just looks at API Calls!

As for HorizontalPodAutoScaler I don't know what that user agent in your screenshot is.

Anyhow if you don't have any of these objects in your cluster. I would say upgrading should be safe for your. You are perfectly ok to stay on 1.25 a it's still supported for now.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be you are  using 1.24v for pod security policy but as per this [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/migrate-from-psp/), With the release of Kubernetes v1.25, PodSecurityPolicy has been removed and migrated to Pod Security Admission and also As per the [kubernetes official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-admission/),

> Kubernetes offers a built-in Pod Security admission controller to
> enforce the Pod Security Standards. Pod security restrictions are
> applied at the namespace level when pods are created.

This means that there is a pod security in built so that needs to upgrade to the latest version that is the reason you are getting this warning.

Likewise, for  `HorizontalPodAutoScaler you are using autoscaling.apiserver.k8s.io/v2beta2` API version of HorizontalPodAutoscaler is no longer served as of v1.26.  So, Migrate manifests and API clients use the **autoscaling.apiserver.k8s.io/v2** API version, available since v1.23. All existing persisted objects are accessible using the new API.  Refer to this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-26#removed-apis-v126) for more information.

**Note :**

> Warning: If you do not update a client or manifest before the 1.26
> upgrade, it will not be able to read/modify existing objects or create
> new objects. The client or manifest will only be able to read, modify,
> or create objects once you update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I wonder is, I do not have any `PodSecurityPolicy` or `HorizontalPodAutoScaler` resource while GKE warns about that.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, kubernetes offers built in pod security admission as you have `gce.gke-metrics-agent` in every cluster. By default kubernetes will offer this in your environment.