# GKE - "Migrate to updated APIs" errors

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a similar problem to this post: [GKE - "Migrate to updated APIs" but cannot find any resources for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76911569/gke-migrate-to-updated-apis-but-cannot-find-any-resources-for-it)

The GKE cluster says that the **gkebackup/agent** calls the **/apis/policy/v1beta1/podsecuritypolicies** API.

[Migrate to supported APIs error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r689A.png)

I am indeed using a protectedapplication to backup certain configmaps from the cluster, but as far as I know this uses the **gkebackup.gke.io/v1alpha2** API.

```
> kubectl get --raw /apis/policy/v1beta1/podsecuritypolicies | jq

Warning: policy/v1beta1 PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+
{
  "kind": "PodSecurityPolicyList",
  "apiVersion": "policy/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "559423101"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "gce.gke-metrics-agent",
        "uid": "05930fb8-da4e-4036-88ef-213f6e8fd3c6",
        "resourceVersion": "553418154",
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-03-17T14:17:52Z",
        ...
  ]
}
```

```
> kubectl describe protectedapplication backup-app

Name:         backup-app
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  gkebackup.gke.io/v1alpha2
Kind:         ProtectedApplication
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-03-24T07:48:27Z
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to how I answered the aftermentioned post. There is a possibility something in the cluster is calling certain API's even if you don't have objects in the cluster created under these API's.

So basically just ignore it!